# Why do we use "i" in loops such as in "for i in range"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, range

Why is "i" often used in learning materials when illustrating loops?

For example, it's used when looping over a `range` function. Using a random number just seems more logical to me since the `range` function is dealing with numbers.

Comment: FYI this question is likely to get down-voted.  It lacks an explicit programming question (and thus an explicit programming answer).

Comment: Check out https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/86904/why-do-most-of-us-use-i-as-a-loop-counter-variable

Comment: I'd suggest you try to do some research before post a question. This link is what you're looking for now. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/86904/why-do-most-of-us-use-i-as-a-loop-counter-variable

Comment: Thanks guys. I will try to improve my next post. This was my first ever.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Asking why we use `i` is kind of like asking why so many people use the letter `x` in math problems. It is mostly because `i` is just a very easy variable to use to represent the current increment in a loop.

I also think you are confused about the place of `i` in a loop. When you use a `range` loop you are saying that you want to count one by one from one number until you hit another. Typically it would look like this

```
for i in range(0, 5):
```

This means I want to count from 0-4 and set `i` to the current loop I am currently on.

A great way to test this.

```
for i in range(0, 5):
  print("i currently equals: ", i)
```

The result will be

```
i currently equals: 0
i currently equals: 1
i currently equals: 2
i currently equals: 3
i currently equals: 4
```

In your question you ask why don't you set `i` to a number and it is because you can not use numbers as variable names. Python cannot accept what you are asking, but if it could it would look like this

```
for 54 in range(0, 5):
  print(54)
```

Try reading up a little more on what variables are and how to properly use them in programming: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Think_Python/Variables,_expressions_and_statements

Comment: wesley... You did it. That extra help was exactly what I needed. I was confused because I didn't understood that "i" was a variable and your explanation made the pieces connect:
for i in range(0, 5):
  print("i currently equals: ", i)

And thanks for the "good luck". Though I don't know how to code yet the beauty/magic of it already seems so clear to me.

Comment: I am so glad to hear this! And just you w8 my friend you are only dipping your toes into a massive ocean... The fact that you are all ready understanding code though means you have a very bright future ahead of you! Here is my advice I will leave you with. Once you get a good handle on python try branching into c++. It has a very similar feel to python since both languages are based from c. Also if you plan on doing coding switch to a UNIX based OS as soon as you can. I would advise trying something easy like Linux Mint. Switching to Linux is something i wish i did from the start. GOOD LUCK!

Comment: Thank you mate! Sorry for my late reply but just landed in Thailand for 2 weeks vacation ;-) I really appreciate you taking the time to giving me these advices and tips, it's so great for a newbie to get support like that. Do you wanna keep in touch?

Answer (score 2):

`i` is used across nearly all programming languages to indicate a counting variable for a **i**teration loop.

Comment: ... but feel free to use a more descriptive name in your own code

Comment: @HansKesting that's true. if you know what those numbers stand for, than you can do something like e.g. `for hour in range(24)`

Comment: Thanks alot! the "iteration" explanation did it. I've tried searching for answers like this but never hit the spot. Now I can rest in peace.

Comment: @CrunchingMyBrain, glad I could help. Feel free to mark my answer as the accepted solution then :)

Answer (score 2):

Answered in Software Engineering Stack Exchange:

[Why do most of us use 'i' as a loop counter variable?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/86911)

> `i` and `j` have typically been used as subscripts in quite a bit of
> math for quite some time (e.g., even in papers that predate
> higher-level languages, you frequently see things like
> "X<sub>i,j</sub>", especially in things like a summation).
>
> When they designed Fortran, they (apparently) decided to allow the
> same, so all variables starting with "I" through "N" default to
> integer, and all others to real (floating point). For those who've
> missed it, this is the source of the old joke "God is real (unless
> declared integer)".
>
> Most people seem to have seen little reason to change that. It's
> widely known and understood, and quite succinct. Every once in a while
> you see something written by some psychotic who thinks there's a real
> advantage to something like:
>
> ```c
> for (int outer_index_variable=0; outer_index_variable < 10; outer_index_variable++)
>     for (int inner_index_variable=0; inner_index_variable < 10; inner_index_variable++)
>         x[outer_index_variable][inner_index_variable] = 0;
> ```
>
> Thankfully this is pretty rare though, and most style guides now point
> out that while long, descriptive variable names *can* be useful, you
> *don't* always need them, especially for something like this where the variable's scope is only a line or two of code.

Comment: If you directly copied the answer from somewhere else, you should not take the credit for the answer. That's why the community wiki option exists.

Comment: Very useful explanation: "I" through "N" default to integer. Thank you!

Comment: @abccd - My apologies. I'm new to stackoverflow and I don't intend to take the credit for the answer, just wanted to help the questioner. I have added the link in the answer. Is that the standard way of answering in here?

Comment: See this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts